# Limit the scope of third-party css with sass

Tags: css, sass

I need to display an SPA in a legacy application (iframes not allowed). The SPA application uses third-party css. Unfortunately, the third-party css is interfering with the styles of the legacy application, and I need to somehow limit its scope. I would like to do something like this in the SPA:

```
<div class="use-third-party-css">
    <!-- SPA -->
</div>
```

In order to be able to do this I have created an scss file:

```
.use-third-party-css { 
     @import "../node_modules/third-party/dist/default";
}
```

Currently it works fine, but it is giving me a warning that the feature importing css is deprecated and will soon be removed.
Is there a way to achieve this "scoping" easier and/or without a warning?
**EDIT:** 
There is also an scss version, I could do something like this:

```
.use-third-party-css { 
     @import "../node_modules/third-party/src/default.scss";
}
```

But it does not work for me because of the following "unexpected" behavior. The following file:

```
@mixin testMixin() {
    &-a > &-b {
       color: black;
   }
}

.c {
   @include testMixin();
}
```

Would be changed into

```
.use-third-party-css .c-a > .use-third-party-css .c-b {
    color: black; 
}
```

Comment: Why not refactoring the scss? Copy all its content inside the `use-third-party-css` maybe. If you have the souce file that would be an easy fix.

Comment: I would like to avoid having to copy third-party scss. Looks a bit messy to me

Comment: Did you eventually solve this?

Comment: No, I did not. First I went with the deprecation warning then the third-party library was replaced and the conflicts were gone.